# Reference error with attachments import from google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, referenceerror

So I have a problem with a script.

What I want it to do is, on form submission, it is to place the attachments to this form into one folder. So the script is creating the folder as I want it to, with the correct name, but the script is not importing the documents that was uploaded to the form into the folder it has created. The script runs from my form responses sheet. Any help will be much appreciated. When I try to run it is says; ReferenceError: "items" is not defined. (line 13, file "Code") Please keep in mind I dont code for a living, this is to make my work easier.

```
Function createStudentFolder() {

   // identify the sheet where the data resides 
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var names = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

   //identify the cell that will be used to name the folder  
   var studentName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 3).getValue();  

   //identify the parent folder the new folder will be in 
   var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById ("0B1r05LzCHjrefnhoMTZ3M1FaVFVxTDBfZDBiR1AxSXpEOUFvanltdmIxd1V3cWw4VGoyVjA");

   var submittedID = items[4].getResponse();

   for (i = 0; i < submittedID.length; i++) { 
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID[i]);

      //create the new folder 
      var newFolder=parentFolder.createFolder(studentName);

   }
}
```

Comment: Which language are you working with?

Comment: Hi Shashwat, just normal google script :-) and it creates the folder perfectly from the form submission, but it does not save the uploaded attachments in the folder :-(

Comment: I would really appreciate your assistance greatly